# Dropout: Redundant representation vs. breaking up co-adaptation

Tags: neural-networks, dropout

Dropout is commonly used to regularize NNs.

On one hand Dropout forces the network to have a redundant representation, since due to the dropout the NN can not rely on specific neurons for the classification.

On the other hand in the original dropout paper[1](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a.old/srivastava14a.pdf) and many other sources state that dropout prevents co-adaptation.

Co-Adaption is very close related to redundancy.

Co-Adaptation means that multiply neurons or conv filters have a similar weight configuration, hence they detect the same feature.

This is also what i understand under a redundant representation. Therefore, i see a contradiction there.

How can you have a redundant representation without Co-Adaptation?